# Clarification: Summation step

Tags: summation

I am reading Concrete Mathematics by Donald Knuth. There is a method to solve summation, particularly for $\sum_{k=0}^n k^2$, called *Expand and contract*.

I don't understand just a single step. i.e. $$\sum_{1\leq k \leq n} k^2 = \sum_{1\leq j \leq k \leq n} k$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to say that $k = \sum_{j=1}^k 1$

$$\sum_{1\leq k \leq n} k^2 = \sum_{1\leq k \leq n} k \left(\sum_{j=1}^k 1\right)= \sum_{1\leq j \leq k \leq n} k$$

Comment: I don't understand you're saying $k = \frac {k(k + 1)}{2}$!

Comment: @Abhisek where?

Comment: my bad, I didn't read it properly